# How to remove characters as '\n' and 'xa0' from scraped data but keep the spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I scraped some data and stored the strings in a list. However the strings contain strange characters:

```
['\nBayern Munich   ',
 '\nWerder Bremen ',
 '\nHamburger SV ',
 '\nFC Schalke 04 ',
 '\nBay. Leverkusen ',
 '\nHertha BSC ',
 '\nBor. Dortmund ',
 '\n1.FC Nuremberg ',
 '\nVfB Stuttgart ',
 "\nBor. M'gladbach ",
 '\n1.FSV Mainz 05 ',
 '\nHannover 96 ',
 '\nArm. Bielefeld ',
 '\nE. Frankfurt \xa0 ',
 '\nVfL Wolfsburg ',
 "\n1.FC K'lautern ",
 '\n1. FC Köln \xa0 ',
 '\nMSV Duisburg \xa0 ']
```

I know how to remove '\n' and '\xa0' but i think the way i do it is not very comfortable. I also want to get rid of the spaces at the end of each string but keep the spaces in the middle.

Actually i removed the characters with list comprehension:

```py
team = [elem.replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','') for elem in team]
team
```

I get the following result:

```
['Bayern Munich   ',
 'Werder Bremen ',
 'Hamburger SV ',
 'FC Schalke 04 ',
 'Bay. Leverkusen ',
 'Hertha BSC ',
 'Bor. Dortmund ',
 '1.FC Nuremberg ',
 'VfB Stuttgart ',
 "Bor. M'gladbach ",
 '1.FSV Mainz 05 ',
 'Hannover 96 ',
 'Arm. Bielefeld ',
 'E. Frankfurt  ',
 'VfL Wolfsburg ',
 "1.FC K'lautern ",
 '1. FC Köln  ',
 'MSV Duisburg  ']
```

What i really want is this:

```
['Bayern Munich',
 'Werder Bremen',
 'Hamburger SV',
 'FC Schalke 04',
 'Bay. Leverkusen',
 'Hertha BSC',
 'Bor. Dortmund',
 '1.FC Nuremberg',
 'VfB Stuttgart',
 "Bor. M'gladbach",
 '1.FSV Mainz 05',
 'Hannover 96',
 'Arm. Bielefeld',
 'E. Frankfurt',
 'VfL Wolfsburg',
 "1.FC K'lautern",
 '1. FC Köln',
 'MSV Duisburg']
```

Can someone explain how to get rid of the spaces in the end of each string? The problem is that the amount of spaces differs between 1-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.strip()` like here:

```
>>> [elem.replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','').strip() for elem in team]
['Bayern Munich', 'Werder Bremen', 'Hamburger SV', 'FC Schalke 04', 'Bay. Leverkusen', 'Hertha BSC', 'Bor. Dortmund', '1.FC Nuremberg', 'VfB Stuttgart', "Bor. M'gladbach", '1.FSV Mainz 05', 'Hannover 96', 'Arm. Bielefeld', 'E. Frankfurt', 'VfL Wolfsburg', "1.FC K'lautern", '1. FC K\xc3\xb6ln', 'MSV Duisburg']
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I simply didnt know about "strip". I will accept this :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
[s.strip() for s in team]
```